# lubridate: inconsistent behavior with timezones

Tags: r, timezone, dplyr, lubridate

Consider the following example

```
 library(lubridate)
 library(tidyverse)

> hour(ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:00:00'))
[1] 0
```

Now,

```
dataframe <- data_frame(time = c(ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:00:00'),
                                 ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:01:00'),
                                 ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:02:00'),
                                 ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:03:00')),
                        value = c(1,2,3,4))

mutate(dataframe,hour = strftime(time, format="%H:%M:%S"),
hour2 = hour(time)) 

# A tibble: 4 × 4
                 time value     hour hour2
               <dttm> <dbl>    <chr> <int>
1 2008-01-03 19:00:00     1 19:00:00    19
2 2008-01-03 19:01:00     2 19:01:00    19
3 2008-01-03 19:02:00     3 19:02:00    19
4 2008-01-03 19:03:00     4 19:03:00    19
```

What is going on here? Why are the dates converted into some local time which I dont event know?

Comment: Yes, `strftime` will use your current time zone. Use `strftime(time, format="%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")` instead.

Comment: thanks but what remains a mystery is why `lubridate:hour` now uses the local time zone whereas the first example shows it correctly extract the hour as being `0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an issue with lubridate, but with the way POSIXct values are combined into a vector.

You have

```
> ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:01:00')
[1] "2008-01-04 00:01:00 UTC"
```

But when combining into a vector you get

```
> c(ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:01:00'), ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:01:00'))
[1] "2008-01-03 19:01:00 EST" "2008-01-03 19:01:00 EST"
```

The reason is that the `tzone` attribute gets lost when combining POSIXct values (see `c.POSIXct`).

```
> attributes(ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:01:00'))
$tzone
[1] "UTC"

$class
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

but

```
> attributes(c(ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:01:00')))
$class
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

What you can use instead is

```
> ymd_hms(c('2008-01-04 00:01:00', '2008-01-04 00:01:00'))
[1] "2008-01-04 00:01:00 UTC" "2008-01-04 00:01:00 UTC"
```

which will use the default `tz = "UTC"` for all arguments.

You also need to pass `tz = "UTC"` into `strftime` because its default is your current time zone (unlike `ymd_hms` which defaults to UTC).